# CGContextStrokePath scaling issue

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, cgcontext

I am working on a drawing App which have two **UIImageViews**. What I would like to do is erase the top UIImageView so that I can see the bottom UIImageView and vice versa. I have implemented all the functionality and its working perfect but the issue happens when I Pan/Zoom the UIImageView using **UIGestureRecognizer** and the I started to erase the Image so the LineWidth is also Zoomed e.g: initialy my eraser width set to 25.0f if I zoom my UIImageView 200% my eraser also zoomed out to 200% i.e from 25.0f to 50.0f which makes everything go crazy. So **My question is How can I remain my eraser to its original width rather than zoomed out/in with Image Zooming?**

Here is my Code:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if (selectedButton == self.Image1Btn)
        currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.ImageCaptureView];
    if (selectedButton == self.Image2Btn)
        currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.ImageCaptureView];

    if (bottomBarSelectedButton == 1)
    {        
        if (selectedButton == self.Image1Btn)
        {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.Image1.frame.size);
            [self.Image1.image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

        }
        if (selectedButton == self.Image2Btn)
        {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.Image2.image.size);
            [self.Image2.image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

        }

        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor.CGColor);
        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
        CGContextBeginPath(context);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y-36);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y-36);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);


        if (selectedButton == self.Image1Btn)
        {
            self.Image1.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            previousPoint1 = [touch locationInView:self.ImageCaptureView];
        }
        if (selectedButton == self.Image2Btn)
        {
            self.Image2.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            previousPoint1 = [touch locationInView:self.ImageCaptureView];
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    recognizer.view.transform = t;
    recognizer.scale = 1;

}
```

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried to solve it?

Comment: @user1118321 Updated question with actual Question

Comment: Don't you need to scale the line width by the inverse of the scale you used to scale the view? (So by 1.0 / recognizer.scale in `handlePinch:`.)

Comment: @user1118321 unfortunately it has worse effect as I do self.lineWidth = self.lineWidth * (1.0f/recognizer.scale); it gives me 3 times bigger line width for eraser.

Comment: OK, so maybe the scale is the inverse of what I thought it was. What if you do this: `self.lineWidth *= recognizer.scale`?

Comment: @user1118321 same 3 times bigger line width effect